# Need assistance with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables that I'm trying to create a query from:
Table 1 (iuieEmployee) ->position number
Table 2 (jbEmployeeH1BInfo) -> position number, LCA number, start date
Table 3 (jbEmployeeLCA) -> LCA number
Table 4 (jbInternationsl) -> Main demographic table

I have a query that works fine where there's only 1 record in each table, but tables 2 and 3 can have multiple records. I want it to find the record with he most recent start date and verify that there is a matching LCA number in the 3rd table and a matching position number int he first table and show me any records where this isn't the case. How can I accomplish this? I currently have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT jbInternational.idnumber, jbInternational.lastname, jbInternational.firstname, jbInternational.midname, 
            jbInternational.campus, jbInternational.universityid, jbInternational.sevisid, jbInternational.citizenship,
            jbInternational.immigrationstatus, jbEmployeeH1BInfo.lcaNumber AS lcaNumber1, jbEmployeeLCA.lcaNumber AS lcaNumber2

FROM (select jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber, MAX(jbEmployeeH1BInfo.approvalStartDate) AS MaxDateStamp FROM [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeH1BInfo GROUP BY idnumber ) my
            INNER JOIN [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeH1BInfo WITH (nolock) ON my.idnumber=jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber AND my.MaxDateStamp=jbEmployeeH1BInfo.approvalStartDate
            INNER JOIN [internationalservices].[dbo].jbInternational WITH (nolock) ON jbInternational.idnumber=jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber 
            inner join [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeLCA ON jbInternational.idnumber = jbEmployeeLCA.idnumber

WHERE jbInternational.idnumber not in(

SELECT DISTINCT jbInternational.idnumber

FROM (select distinct jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber, MAX(jbEmployeeH1BInfo.approvalStartDate) AS MaxDateStamp
            FROM [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeH1BInfo GROUP BY idnumber ) my
            INNER JOIN [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeH1BInfo WITH (nolock) ON my.idnumber=jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber AND my.MaxDateStamp=jbEmployeeH1BInfo.approvalStartDate
            INNER JOIN [internationalservices].[dbo].jbInternational WITH (nolock) ON jbInternational.idnumber=jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber 
            inner join [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeLCA ON jbInternational.idnumber = jbEmployeeLCA.idnumber
            AND jbEmployeeH1BInfo.lcaNumber = jbEmployeeLCA.lcaNumber)
```

Table Schema:

```
create table iuieEmployee(idnumber int, POS_NBR varchar(8));
insert into iuieEmployee values(123456, '470V13');
insert into iuieEmployee values(123457, '98X000');
insert into iuieEmployee values(123458, '98X000');
insert into iuieEmployee values(123455, '98X000');

create table jbEmployeeH1BInfo (idnumber int, approvalStartDate smalldatetime, lcaNumber varchar(20), positionNumber varchar(200));
insert into jbEmployeeH1BInfo values (123456, 07/01/2012, '1-200-3000', '98X000');
insert into jbEmployeeH1BInfo values (123456, 07/30/2013, '1-200-4000', '470V13');
insert into jbEmployeeH1BInfo values (123457, 07/01/2012, '1-200-5000', '98X000');
insert into jbEmployeeH1BInfo values (123458, 07/01/2012, '1-200-6000', '98X000');
insert into jbEmployeeH1BInfo values (123455, 07/30/2014, '1-200-7000', '98X000');
insert into jbEmployeeH1BInfo values (123455, 07/01/2012, '1-200-8000', '470V13');

create table jbEmployeeLCA (idnumber int, lcaNumber varchar(20));  
insert into jbEmployeeLCA values (123456, 1-200-3000);
insert into jbEmployeeLCA values (123456, 1-200-4111);
insert into jbEmployeeLCA values (123457, 1-200-5000);
insert into jbEmployeeLCA values (123458, 1-200-6000);
insert into jbEmployeeLCA values (123455, 1-200-7000);
insert into jbEmployeeLCA values (123455, 1-200-8000);

create table jbInternational(idnumber int);
insert into jbInternational values(123456);
insert into jbInternational values(123457);
insert into jbInternational values(123458);
insert into jbInternational values(123455);
```

Should only return 1 line:
123456, 07/30/2013, '1-200-4000'
but is instead returning two lines:
123456, 07/30/2013, '1-200-4000 (not matching 1-200-4111)
123456, 07/30/2013, '1-200-4000 (not matching 1-200-3000)
It shouldn't return the second row because the position number with the -3000 lca number doesn't have the most current date.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is hard to understand. I guess if you could explain it well, then you could probably write the query yourself. Here's what I think you meant:

Employee contains the main records.

You want to find all idnumbers such that

- idnumber is in International
- the H1BInfo record with the most recent approvalStartDate does not have an LCA number matching the LCA record

The first thing to do is to simplify that H1BInfo table. We are only looking for the rows with the most recent approvalStartDate. We can do that by partitioning by idnumber and ordering by approvalStartDate:

```
with rankedH1BInfo as (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber
            ORDER BY jbEmployeeH1BInfo.approvalStartDate desc) as r 
    FROM [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeH1BInfo
)
```

Let's only get the first row of each partition:

```
, MostRecentH1BInfo as (
    SELECT * FROM rankedH1BInfo
    WHERE r = 1
)
```

Now we can do the join to find all the good ones:

```
, goodIDs as (
    SELECT i.idnumber
    FROM [internationalservices].[dbo].jbInternational i WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeLCA l WITH (NOLOCK) on l.idnumber = i.idnumber
    JOIN MostRecentH1BInfo h WITH (NOLOCK) on h.idnumber = i.idnumber
    JOIN iuieEmployee e WITH (NOLOCK) on e.positionNumber = h.positionNumber
    WHERE h.lcaNumber = l.lcaNumber
)
```

To put it all together and get the ones where this is false:

```
with rankedH1BInfo as (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber
            ORDER BY jbEmployeeH1BInfo.approvalStartDate desc) as r 
    FROM [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeH1BInfo
), MostRecentH1BInfo as (
    SELECT * FROM rankedH1BInfo
    WHERE r = 1
), goodIDs as (
    SELECT i.idnumber
    FROM [internationalservices].[dbo].jbInternational i WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeLCA l WITH (NOLOCK) on l.idnumber = i.idnumber
    JOIN MostRecentH1BInfo h WITH (NOLOCK) on h.idnumber = i.idnumber
    JOIN iuieEmployee e WITH (NOLOCK) on e.positionNumber = h.positionNumber
    WHERE h.lcaNumber = l.lcaNumber
)
SELECT DISTINCT jbInternational.idnumber, jbInternational.lastname, jbInternational.firstname, jbInternational.midname, 
        jbInternational.campus, jbInternational.universityid, jbInternational.sevisid, jbInternational.citizenship,
        jbInternational.immigrationstatus, jbEmployeeH1BInfo.lcaNumber AS lcaNumber1, jbEmployeeLCA.lcaNumber AS lcaNumber2
FROM (select jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber, MAX(jbEmployeeH1BInfo.approvalStartDate) AS MaxDateStamp FROM [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeH1BInfo GROUP BY idnumber ) my
            INNER JOIN [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeH1BInfo WITH (nolock) ON my.idnumber=jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber AND my.MaxDateStamp=jbEmployeeH1BInfo.approvalStartDate
            INNER JOIN [internationalservices].[dbo].jbInternational WITH (nolock) ON jbInternational.idnumber=jbEmployeeH1BInfo.idnumber 
            inner join [internationalservices].[dbo].jbEmployeeLCA ON jbInternational.idnumber = jbEmployeeLCA.idnumber
WHERE jbInternational.idnumber not in (select idnumber from goodIDs)
```

Comment: This gave me the same results as my query is getting. The problem is if a particular record has 1 position but 2 lca numbers in each table and none match, that record is returned twice. I just want to see each id once if there's no match to that lca record with the most recent start date.

Comment: @LaurenRobinson I am not sure what you mean. Can you create a SQL Fiddle with a sample schema and data to illustrate your point?